# Stopwatch with sound at a certain time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a project that contains a timer, I'm trying to put an alarm or music to play when the time of 12 minutes is reached. How could this be possible? If anyone can help me, I'm a beginner.

**Buttons that start, pause, and reset the timer**

```
 switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.bt_control:

            if (btControl.getText().equals("Play")) {
                this.startService(intent);
                cmPasstime.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                cmPasstime.start();
                btControl.setText("Stop");

            } else if (btControl.getText().equals("Stop")) {
                this.stopService(intent);
                cmPasstime.stop();
                btControl.setText("Play");
            } else if (btControl.getText().equals("Play")) {
                this.startService(intent);
                cmPasstime.start();
                btControl.setText("Stop");
            }

            break;



        case R.id.bt_reset:
            reset();
            break;
 }
```

**Stopwatch**

```
  @Override
public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {

    seconds++;
    cmPasstime.setText(formatseconds());
}

public String formatseconds() {
    String hh = seconds / 3600 > 9 ? seconds / 3600 + "" : "0" + seconds
            / 3600;
    String mm = (seconds % 3600) / 60 > 9 ? (seconds % 3600) / 60 + ""
            : "0" + (seconds % 3600) / 60;
    String ss = (seconds % 3600) % 60 > 9 ? (seconds % 3600) % 60 + ""
            : "0" + (seconds % 3600) % 60;

    return hh + " : " + mm + " : " + ss;
}
```

**Reset**

```
  private void reset() {

    tvPasstime.setText("00:00:00");
    cmPasstime.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    cmPasstime.stop();
    btControl.setText("Play");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Firebase JobDispatcher, this library will schedule job in background to do something at specified time.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android